# excpetion error :Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have seen all the exception errors but I didn't get my problem. I have tblsecondary which have streetId,streetName,fasileOne,fasileTwo. I am using a datagridview to populate a row when I select a value in datagridviewcomboboxcolumn, but its giving me an exception error :

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> on dataGridView7[e.RowIndex, 2].Value = drFound["fasileOne"];

The code is :

```
private void dataGridView7_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if ((e.RowIndex >= 0) && (e.ColumnIndex == 1)) // Assuming this is the streetId
            {
                int streetId = Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView7.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
                DataRow drFound = tblSecondary.Rows.Find(streetId);
                if (drFound == null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("ddhhdhd");
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView7[e.RowIndex, 2].Value = drFound["fasileOne"];
                    dataGridView7[e.RowIndex, 3].Value = drFound["fasileTwo"];
                }
            }
```

Here is the datatable am using :

```
public IncidentForm()
tblSecondary = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd2 = cnn.CreateCommand();
cmd2.CommandText = "select * from street";
SqlDataAdapter sdr2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd2.Connection = cnn;
sdr2.Fill(tblSecondary);
tblSecondary.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { tblSecondary.Columns["streetId"] };
}
```

Comment: It's column then row, not row then column.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158656(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yeah it worked thank u very much Sir.

Comment: what event should i use that when i change the 1st combobox value all is removed until i choose the 2nd combobox so that the row is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the [indexer on the DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158656(v=vs.110).aspx).
The first index is the ColumnIndex, the second the RowIndex

```
 dataGridView7[2, e.RowIndex].Value = drFound["fasileOne"];
 dataGridView7[3, e.RowIndex].Value = drFound["fasileTwo"];
```